# python unittest2 - exposing test method name to setup method

Tags: python, python-2.6, unittest2

I need to find the name of the test method about to be run from within the `SetUp()` method that unittest runs before each test. How can I do this without running every test method seperately?

Example:

```
class Testing(unittest2.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        # wish i could write:
        string = getNextTestMethodName()

    def test_example(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(0,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not even self.id() is needed:

```
def setUp( self ):
    logger.info( '# setUp for %s' % ( self, ))
```

typical output:

```
# setUp for test_mainframe_has_been_constructed (__main__.BasicFunctionality_FT)
```

... where "test_mainframe_has_been_constructed" is the method.

So `repr( self )`, presumably, if you just want the string - then slice and dice, observing that the method name ends with the opening bracket (or first white space).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [self.shortDescription()](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.shortDescription) that will give you the name of the test (or the docstring associated with the test), and this, even in the `setUp/tearDown` methods.

EDIT: maybe [self.id()](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id) is enough, it provide only the test name (thanks to @Blair).

Comment: Or [self.id()](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id), which returns the name of the test case, which is usually the name of the test method.

Comment: thanks cedric&blair, after reviewing unittest.py i realized that the testcase holds the name of the testmethod currently running in self._testMethodName. this fills my needs as id() isn't good cause i have several testmethods within my testcase class